# SAP Crystal Reports & VS 2015

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

How to integrate "SAP Crystal Reports" with VS 2015 after installing the MSI files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To integrate "SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio" into VS 2010 or 2012 (SP 7 and higher) or VS 2013 (SP 9 or higher) or VS 2015 RC (SP14) - VS 2015 (fully - SP 15), you must run the Install Executable. Running the MSI will not fully integrate Crystal Reports into VS. MSI files by definition are for runtime distribution only.